# ROS2 How to know if GUI is available in launch file

Tags: rviz, roslaunch

In the launch file, I am calling the package RVIZ to visualise some data in my package. However, when using `roslaunch` via SSH command, it fails because the GUI is unavailable. Is there a way to not launch a node when the GUI is not running?

My launch file is calling other packages, so I guess the falling of RVIZ is not blocking everything, but I would like to avoid the error message.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Without much logic, I would simply define an `arg` and then use the `if` attribute to invoke the node. This way, I can pass true/false to set/reset the attribute while calling this launch file. An example is shown [here](https://github.com/ravijo/rviz_skeleton_visualization/blob/1ea2b513a65be32834f9fccf20a5307dc95b0228/launch/realtime_visualization.launch#L23-L28)

Comment: Thanks for the example, I think to be fast I will use this option.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem, and two common solutions have come up in ROS 1 that still work here:

- Allow command line parameters to your launch files (as per @ravi 's suggestion). So your GUI defaults to off unless you explicitly turn it on.
- Use more than one launch file. It's common to have a 'robot bringup' launch file and a 'robot visualization' launch file.

But, if we're in ROS 2, our launch files are Python. Python lets us check environment variables, and we know that if we can get the `DISPLAY` environment variable, the X11 system is trying to use a display. This is a reasonable assumption since it's the same check a lot of the X11 APIs make.

With that in mind, here's the `turtlesim` example launch file, modified to display RViz2 if a display is available:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
import os

DISPLAY_AVAILABLE:bool
if os.environ.get("DISPLAY"):
    print("X11 is available")
    DISPLAY_AVAILABLE = True
else:
    print("X11 is not available")
    DISPLAY_AVAILABLE = False


def generate_launch_description():
    nodes = [
        Node(
            package="turtlesim",
            namespace="turtlesim1",
            executable="turtlesim_node",
            name="sim",
        ),
        Node(
            package="turtlesim",
            namespace="turtlesim2",
            executable="turtlesim_node",
            name="sim",
        ),
        Node(
            package="turtlesim",
            executable="mimic",
            name="mimic",
            remappings=[
                ("/input/pose", "/turtlesim1/turtle1/pose"),
                ("/output/cmd_vel", "/turtlesim2/turtle1/cmd_vel"),
            ],
        ),
    ]
    if DISPLAY_AVAILABLE:
        nodes.append(
            Node(
                package="rviz2",
                executable="rviz2",
                name="rviz2",
            )
        )
    return LaunchDescription(nodes)
```

The specific changes here are:

- importing the `os` module
- using `os` to check for the `DISPLAY` environment variable
- using the results of that check to append rviz to the list of nodes.

I'd be careful with this sort of thing: you can imagine a very difficult to diagnose system if launching becomes highly conditional, rather than consistent. But in cases like this I imagine it's fine.

Comment: For the third solution, that means I will have to translate my launch file from XML to Python? I can also use the two first options that seem fine, I guess.

Comment: @DarkPatate Yes, I'm not aware of any "check for ___" mechanism as a part of the launch file toolkit, so the only approach to do that would be to abuse the Python launch files.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sorry, I cannot upvote yet because I just registered for this exchange.